# Будет ли данная реализация производительней?

Tags: многопоточность, производительность, шаблоны-проектирования

```
public class Consumer<T> where T : class 
{
    private readonly Queue<T> queue;
    private readonly object lockObject;

    public Consumer()
    {
        queue = new Queue<T>();
        lockObject = new object();
    }

    public void Set(T entity)
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(entity);
        }
    }

    public T Get()
    {
        T entity = null;
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            if (queue.Count != 0)
            {
                entity = queue.Dequeue();
            }
        }
        return entity;
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return queue.Count; }
    }
}
```

Предпологаю такой метод в продюсере:

```
    static void Producer()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (consumer.Count > 0)
            {
                var entity = consumer.Get();
                //check (entity != null)
                //do some work
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }
```

В чем выгода от методов Pulse и PulseAll?
Спасибо

Упс - думал данный вопрос будет привязан к [исследованию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/research/221526/%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-producer-consumer-pattern)

Интересует реализация на C# без BlockingCollection.

Comment: Не переживайте, он и так приявязан! Вы зарегистрировались чтобы задать этот вопрос? Желание БЕШШШШШЕННОЕ ИМЕЮ! Как говорит Каха. Ждем развернуто наискорейщего ответа!

Comment: На данный момент меня интересует только этот ответ, так как занимаюсь решением подобной задачи. Данный форум привлекает относительно давно, но зарегестрироваться решил только сейчас, когда появилось что "сказать".

Comment: А до этого не было вопросов? Ок! Ждем все вместе ответа! )))

Comment: Вопросы были, но либо руки не доходили, либо удавалось самостоятельно решать.

Comment: Я читал на мсдн про метод Pulse и Monitor.Enter\Exit, но разницу не понимаю (точней не понимаю необходимость использовать Pulse). После Exit к данному участку кода может получить доступ один из ожидающих потоков, тогда зачем об этом сигнализировать при помощьи Pulse...

Comment: @mister, не совсем понял вопрос.

Вы хотите сравнить этот код с кодом на `C#` в ИССЛЕДОВАНИЯХ и спрашиваете, зачем в том коде в методе  .enqueue() вызывается Monitor.Pulse(), а в .Stop() Monitor.PulseAll()?

Обратите внимание, там в .dequeue() есть вызов Monitor.Wait(), который отправляет спать потребителя, если очередь пуста.

Так вот, Pulse() и PulseAll() будят спящих, когда потребовалось.

В Вашем же примере в Get() никогда нет ожидания данных, если очередь пуста будет вброшено исключение.

Comment: Да - вы все правильно поняли, только с учетом того, что я собираюсь вызывать метод Get в случае, когда в очереди есть элементы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начнём с того, что ваша имплементация некорректна: если очередь `queue` пуста, `queue.Dequeue()` выбросит исключение.

Попробуем исправить проблему, переписав функцию так:

```
public T Get()
{
    lock (lockObject)
    {
        if (queue.Count > 0)
            return queue.Dequeue();
        else
            ? // здесь мы в тупике
    }
}
```

Что должно быть в `else`? Мы должны дождаться условия: в очередь поступил новый элемент. На время ожидания мы должны, понятно, отдать блокировку. То, что у нас есть блокировка, означает лишь, что наша структура данных *свободна*, но не то, что в ней *есть элементы*.

Можно, конечно, переименовать функцию в `TryGet` и разрешить ей вернуть `null` в `else`, но тогда поток-consumer будет вынужден крутить "busy-wait" до тех пор, пока в очереди не появятся элементы. Или завести *условие* и ожидать его — именно это и делает `Monitor.Wait`/`Monitor.Pulse` в коде из исследования.

---

Исправленный вариант всё ещё не очень хорош: он использует [busy wait](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting), чтобы дождаться появления заданий в очереди. С одной стороны, цикл consumer'а выполняет *слишком много* работы, много раз опрашивая состояние очереди, в то время как consumer в исследовании выполняется лишь по сигналу, что в очереди есть элементы. С другой стороны, вы заведомо ограничиваете скорость реакции consumer'а константой внутри `Sleep`. Это значит, что (1) в среднем половина этой константы будет потрачена впустую, (2) реакция приложения на попытку закрытия (когда вы реализуете `Stop`) тоже будет "отложена" на в среднем половину данной константы, ну и конечно (3) вы впустую гоняете процессор в consumer-потоке.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я пропустил подробности своей реализации "продюсера" и предпологал работать с данным классом примерно следующим образом:

        static void Producer()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (consumer.Count > 0)
                {
                    var entity = consumer.Get();
                    logger.WarnFormat("Got [{0}] from queue.", entity);
                    //do some work
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }

Ну и стопа у меня не хватает.

Comment: Правильно ли я вас понял, что в случае с моей реализацией продюсера я получаю на выходе такое же как у вас качественное решение?

Comment: Наберусь наглости и добавлю свои 5 коп в вашу реализацию:

- не должна ли функция Main быть статической для успешной компиляции?

- что за свойство Empty у объекта Queue<T>?

Comment: @mister: всё ещё неправильно: вы _не можете_ опрашивать разделяемое свойство `consumer.Count` не под lock'ом. Если вы всё же воспользуетесь `lock`'ом внутри реализации `Count`, между запросом `Count` и вызовом `Get` элемент может исчезнуть из очереди, и будет креш.

---
Да, `Main` должна быть статической, сейчас исправлю. `Empty` — это из `Linq`, можно воспользоваться просто `Count`.

Comment: В пространстве имен System.Linq ненаходит у меня свойство Empty (простите за упрямство). Спасибо за ответы. Если бы мог, то добавил в исследовании комментарий, но код до сих пор не компилируемый из-за все тех же статических членов! 


Метод Consumer() должен быть статическим, а также используемые ним переменные ;)

Comment: Там нужно было просто `using System.Linq` и `Empty` заменить на `Empty()`.

Переписал код в исследовании на `Count` :-) Обновите страницу.

Comment: @mister: А, понял в чём проблема с компиляцией. Исправил, обновите ещё раз.